# Как открыть xls из папки sdcard/download/rasp.xls для парса

Tags: java, android

Нужно открыть .xls файл из папки sdcard/download/rasp.xls для парса. xls загружается с сайта в папку download. В данный момент он открывается из папки assets. 
Так выглядит начало кода для парса.

```
try {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open("rasp.xls");
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
        Sheet s = wb.getSheet(0);
        int row = s.getRows();
        int col = s.getColumns();
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте открыть файл, не указывая прямо название папки sdcard, так как на некоторых устройствах это может не сработать.

```
final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + "download" + File.separator + "rasp.xls";
File file = new File(path);
if (file.exists()) {
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
    ...
}
```

`if(file.exists())` проверяет, что такой файл найден.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.